# How to cast List<A> to List<B>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How do I cast `List<SelectVacancyDetails_Result>` to `List< SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend>`
where class `SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend` is inherited from class `SelectVacancyDetails_Result`.

I tried below but no luck

```
   List<SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend> vacExtList = vacList.Cast<SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend>().ToList();
```

(Basically i want all list properties value to be copied over)

Comment: "but no luck" doesn't tell us what happened when you tried. If you'd explained that, you'd have avoided the answer that doesn't help.

Comment: @Verarind  sorry not clear

Comment: The code you wrote does exactly what you want. What is the problem? Do you have some objects of the base type in your list? If so `.OfType<T>()` is your friend.

Comment: You're attempting to use inheritance backwards.

Comment: I tried .OfType() it throws no exception  but doesn't copy list values across either

Comment: Okay - after reading all the answers I think I've a wrong asumption: I thought that you have a List declared as `List<A>` but it contains intances of type `B` with `B : A`. Then Casting is valid. Maybe that's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance does not work that way. With `class Derived : Base`, it is not possible to "cast" an object with [runtime type](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexghi/archive/2009/05/20/compile-time-type-vs-runtime-type-of-a-variable.aspx) `Base` to `Derived`. You'll need to either copy all properties manually or use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: Can you provide be code to do the  same using AutoMapper please?

Answer (score 7):

If all the elements are *actually* of type `SelectVacancyDetails_Result` (not `SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend`) then you can't just cast. The simplest approach would be to create a constructor in `SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend` which copied the properties - or just used composition instead of inheritance, potentially - and then you can use:

```
var vacExtList = vacList.Select(vac => new SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend(vac))
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend> vacExtList = vacList.Select(x => (SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend)x).ToList();
```

Comment: getting exception: Unable to cast object of type 'DataModel.SelectVacancyDetails_Result' to type 'Source.Models.SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend'.

Comment: This should be the same like `.Cast<SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend>().ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, if as you have stated:

`SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend` inherits `SelectVacancyDetails_Result`

Then you can't cast an object of type `SelectVacancyDetails_Result` to type `SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend`.

You can cast `SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend` to type `SelectVacancyDetails_Result`, but not the other way.

You will need to project your properties into the list of base class items instead:

```
var vacExtList = vacList.Select(v => new SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend() {
   PropertyA = v.PropertyA,
   ...
});
```

---

I would also note that having a need to do this is a bit of a code smell - there is something wrong with your inheritance chain.

Answer (score 0):

If stack item's solution doesn't work, it's perfhaps because one of the item can't be casted. (Maybe it's an instance of a less specific type)

what you could do is only get the element that could be casted, and use the following code:

```
var vacExtList = vacList.OfType<SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend>();
```

**EDIT**:

This solution assumes that SelectVacancyDetails_ResultExtend inherits from SelectVacancyDetails_Result, obviously.

Comment: How can i get elements?

Comment: I'm confused: I'm not sure I understand your question, could you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. However you can try this solution:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var vacancies = new List<Vacancy>
        {
            new Vacancy {Id = 1, Details = "flat"},
            new Vacancy {Id = 2, Details = "restaurant"}
        };


        List<VacancyExtended> vacanciesExtended = vacancies.Select(p => new VacancyExtended(p)).ToList();


        foreach (var v in vacanciesExtended)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v.Details);

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


public class Vacancy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }

    public Vacancy(){ }
    public Vacancy(Vacancy vacancy)
    {
        Id = vacancy.Id;
        Details = vacancy.Details;
    }
}
public class VacancyExtended : Vacancy
{
    public VacancyExtended(Vacancy vacancy) : base(vacancy)
    {

    }

    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a typical problem. Other then use constructor in your derived class or 3rd party libs like `AutoMapper` you can also create your custom extension method with `Reflection` it'd much slower so don't use it if you're working with in bottleneck of some sort and use it only if performance is not something that you aren't really worry about or if you can't modify your derived class and by some reason don't want to use `AutoMapper`. These example covers only typical EF models with properties (no fields).

So the method is :

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static IEnumerable<T2> ConvertRange<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> collection)
        where T1 : class
        where T2 : class, new()
    {
        List<T2> elements = new List<T2>();

        PropertyInfo[] propsT2 = typeof(T2).GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo[] propsT1 = typeof(T1).GetProperties()
            .Where(p => propsT2.Any(p2 => p2.Name == p.Name)).ToArray();

        propsT1.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
        propsT2.OrderBy(p => p.Name);

        foreach (T1 item in collection)
        {
            T2 newEl = new T2();

            for (int i = 0; i < propsT1.Length; i++)
                propsT2[i].SetValue(newEl, propsT1[i].GetValue(item));

            elements.Add(newEl);
        }

        return elements;
    }
}
```

Example :

```
    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    class Manager
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> ps = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person() { Name ="Alex", Age = 30 },
            new Person() { Name ="Michael", Age = 22 }
        };

        List<Manager> mgr = ps.ConvertRange<Person, Manager>().ToList();

        foreach (var item in mgr)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name + "   " + item.Age);

        Console.ReadKey();
   }
```

}

Output :

```
Alex     30
Michael  22
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `AutoMapper`

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooBar>();

    List<Foo> randomFoos = new List<Foo>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        randomFoos.Add(new Foo());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("### Random foos");
    randomFoos.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    Console.WriteLine("### Converted foos");
    Mapper.Map<List<FooBar>>(randomFoos)
            .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n")
                        .Substring(6);
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        this.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(property => builder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(this))));

        builder.AppendLine();

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}

public class FooBar : Foo
{
    public FooBar()
    {
        this.Description = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                                .Substring(12);
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```